# T-SQL: How to all Full Text Index to include new columns?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, full-text-search, fulltext-index

I am hoping this is not a repeat, but I created my index and need to include more columns from my table to the index. I have been searching around, however, the general response is to delete it and start over.

Is there any way to just alter the Full Text Index to include my new columns?

This is what I have been playing around with according to documentation:

```
USE [mydb]
GO
ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX ON [dbo].[output]  
{   
   ADD ('col1', 'col2',' col3', 'col4', 'col5', 'col6')  //Error is here

}  
;
GO
```

The error I receive is :
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near '{'.

Comment: Haven't used full text indexing before, but looking at command syntax, I think you dont need the single-quotes around your column names.

Comment: I was also trying to figure out how to do this using the GUI

Comment: Does it work without the single quotes?

Comment: Remove '{' and '}' from the query and then run.

Comment: That fixed it. Thanks Jamie

Comment: @Paradigm, Which one worked removing Single quotes or removing { } or both?